# useEffect causing infinite looping with constant dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

`useEffect` is getting triggered even though the dependency array has constant object.

I tried extracting the logic and put the object in `useState`

```js
const payload = {
    limit: 5,
    offset: 0,
    filterBy: 'All',
};

useEffect(() => {
    const defaultPayload = {
        limit: 10,
        offset: 0,
        filterBy: 'All',
    };
        dispatch({ type: RANDOM_CONST, payload: payload || defaultPayload });
}, [dispatch, payload]);
```

It should trigger only when `payload` changes. Since, `payload` is a constant, it should just run once and note infinite times.

Comment: show whole code and not snippets, where is dispatch coming from?

Comment: I'm not sure why u need `payload` and `defaultPayload` if they are both "constants"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems that may cause the re-render, notice that the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) makes a **shallow comparison** with the `dep-array` values:

1. `payload` is a new object on every render, therefore `oldPayload === payload` always `false`, causes the `useEffect` to run.
2. If `dispatch` comes from 3rd party library (like [react-redux hook](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch)), it might be making a new `dispatch` reference on every render, therefore again `oldDispatch === dispatch` is aways `false` and causes `useEffect` to run.

To fix it, you can move the "constant object" to the outer scope (which will run once), and use `useCallback` hook if you passing the `dispatch`.

> Example from `react-redux` [docs:](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) When passing a callback using dispatch to a child component, it is recommended to memoize it with `useCallback`, since otherwise child components may render unnecessarily due to the changed reference.

```
const payload = {
  limit: 5,
  offset: 0,
  filterBy: 'All'
};

const App = () => {
  //                   v Memoize it if passing as a callback,
  //                     check in library docs if there is a new instance
  //                     on every render
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: RANDOM_CONST, payload });
  }, []);

  return;
};
```

> Note: There is no indication in question where the `dispatch` function comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the objects to JSON strings and compare them inside your useEffect hook:

```
JSON.stringify(oldValue) === JSON.stringify(newValue) // true
```

Note that object keys should have the same order:

```
JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}) === JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}) // true
JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}) === JSON.stringify({b: 2, a: 1}) // false
```